# Potential deadlock using Proc SQL Update in SAS

Tags: sql, error-handling, sas, sql-update, deadlock

I am trying to update a variable 'clnwash' in a dataset based on multiple conditions in a different dataset using prog sql update. I'm new to SAS and I'm having a hard time getting the following code to finish running:

```
data amlgroup.amlgroup_7;
set amlgroup.amlgroup_6;
clnwash = 1;
run;

proc sql;
update amlgroup.amlgroup_7 as a
set clnwash = 0
where exists
(select * from amlgroup.amlgroup_2 as b
    where a.patid = b.patid and b.fill_dt >= a.washout and b.fill_dt <= a.out1end_dt);
quit;
```

The data step works just fine. When the program gets to the proc sql step, the program ever ends, which is why I think I've created a deadlock. Any thoughts on this are appreciated.

When I run my original code, the program never finishes, even days later. I have tried separating the data step and the proc sql step into separate programs; when I submit the proc sql step separately, either the program never ends or I get
`ERROR: A lock is not available for <dataset> ERROR: Lock held by process 137726`

Attempting to correct the issue, I tried including 'waitfor delay '00:00:07' after the 'where exists' statement, but I get a syntax error and the program doesn't run at all.

Comment: If you change the code to use a work dataset, i.e. `work.amlgroup_7` instead of `amlgroup.amlgroup_7` and it suddenly works, that would be evidence that someone else is locking `amlgroup.amlgroup_7`.

Comment: Can you explain the overall goal of your analysis?  Perhaps trying to use a specific method, like the UPDATE statement of PROC SQL, is not the right approach to solve your actual problem.  Perhaps there is a better method that will not take so long.

Answer (score 0):

What client are you using? (Display manager, Enterprise Guide, SAS Studio, VA, etc...) and what kind of machine is your SAS code running on? (local or remote Window/Linux)

Somewhat posssibilities:

- The libref `amlgroup` may be pointing to a library (folder) that is accessible to other users (for example, if you run your code on a SAS Server) and they might have a lock on the data set. Use `%PUT &=SYSPROCESSID;` to see if your sesssion process id is the same as the one in the ERROR message.

  - If the process ids don't match use operating system tools to see what the command line of the offending process id is.
- You may have the data set open in a data viewer.

Comment: I am using SAS Studio and it is running on a remote Linux system. I am also the only user for the library, which is what has been confusing me (all the other advice I've seen deals with multiple users accessing the same file).

Answer (score 0):

Why make TABLE 7 and then immediately start making changes to it? Why not just make it the way you want it to begin with?

Looks to me like you just want to do a LEFT JOIN.

```
proc sql;
create table data amlgroup.amlgroup_7 as 
  select a.*
       , not missing(b.fill_dt) as clnwash
  from amlgroup.amlgroup_6 a
  left join amlgroup.amlgroup_2 b
  on a.patid = b.patid
    and b.fill_dt between a.washout and a.outlend_dt
;
quit;
```

Comment: I am working with pharmacy data, involving multiple refills for medications over time. My data are organized at the refill level. I ultimately will only retain 1 prescription fill per unique individual for my study, if that individual has a fill meets all of my inclusion criteria. The goal of this code is to apply one of those inclusion criteria. I want to create a flag 'clnwash'  for each refill that indicates if another fill for the same medication occurred  recently before (between 'washout' and 'out1end_dt'.) I am searching through an older version of my data to base this flag on.

Comment: If you want to tell if a refill is too close just use a data step to process the fills in date order and calculate the difference in days between the current fill and the previous one.  No joining needed. No SQL updates needed.  If you have 12 flags to create and you cannot do it one step then do it into multiple datasets and just merge them.

Comment: Thank you, I'll be giving this approach a try instead!